# How to use jsonschema library via source code without pip install

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I want to use the jsonschema library. I need to use validate function to validate the JSON schema but I can't install the library using `pip` command due to some restrictions on the server. How can I use the source code of library and implement it in the code?

I can't use this command `pip install jsonschema` to install the library. Need to use the source code of library.

Comment: Is `pip` installed on the server? What problem do you run into if you were to use this command on the server?

Comment: What other approaches do you have on the server: is Git or Docker installed?

Comment: The real question here is why would you need an external library if pip is disabled ? You might need to understand why is it disable in the first place